# While catching exeption why do we use the Exception's subclasses as the o/p clearly gives us the exact exception?

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Test{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
  try{  
   int data=25/0;  
   System.out.println(data);  
  }  
  catch( ArithmeticException e)
       {
         System.out.println(e);
       }  
  }  
}
```

o/p:java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

In this code even if I catch the exception using the **ArithmaticException** class or directly the **Exception** class, the o/p is the same. Then why do we use the subclasses in different catch statements instead of directly using **Exception** class everytime?

Comment: There are situations where more than one exception might happen and you want to do different things in each case

Comment: Each exception can be handled differently depending on its type. You can use `catch(ExceptionFoo ef){handleFoo(ef)}catch(ExceptionBar eb){handleBar(eb)}`. Using common ancestor will allow you to specify common handling mechanisms for all exceptions of that type (including subtype).

Answer (score 3):

You should never use `catch(Exception)`, as that will catch not just the exception you are interested in, but also unintendedly any `RuntimeException` (because RuntimeException extends Exception) that may have occurred

Comment: We catch only runtime exception dude. Y would i even care to handle compile time exceptions ?

Comment: You should only use `catch(Exception)` when you are trying to catch unintended or unknown `RuntimeException`'s and by definition you won't know the type of an unintended or unknown `RuntimeException`.  otherwise you should catch the most specific Exception Types that could be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can show messages with more information according to the error and if the error is not within your predictions, you can display a generic message.

In response to question in comments:

```
try {
    int data = 25 / 0;
    System.out.println(data);
}
catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println("Wrong numbers to process");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Other error message here.");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    /*Here i dont know possible errors in my code, just show a generic message and try resolve the problem for your client.*/ 
     System.out.println("Something wrong./n" + e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: How do u know if the error is out of ur prediction? And how do u handle it ?

Comment: Something like that.
    try{  
        int data=25/0;  
        System.out.println(data);  
    }catch( ArithmeticException e){
         System.out.println("Wrong numbers to process");
 }catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("Other error message here.");
 }catch(Exception e){
  /*Here i dont know possible errors in my code, 
  just show a generic message and try resolve the problem for your client.*/
  System.out.println("Something wrong./n" + e.getMessage());
    }

Comment: The final `catch (Exception e)` block is bad practice - as explained by ControlAltDel, any other exceptions that arise should be allowed to propagate upwards as they're unexpected, so you want to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes you want to catch only ArithmeticException or NumberFormatException. Exception class contains ArithmeticException, NumberFormatException and the other Exception sub classes.